# Huawei Map not loading when download from huawei app gallery

Tags: android, mapkit, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

Hello we have published our app to huawei app gallery.

I have MapHelper class in my app.

In this class every methods work with which services enabled ( gms or hms )

When i run at development ( or get release apk ) it works, i can show huawei map

But when i download via huawei app gallery map is open but now rendering.

[image]

when i look at the logs app when downloaded from app gallery and click the map button i can show these errors

[image]

what should i do ?

Comment: Seems to be it's wrong signing cert problem. Make sure that you add SHA-256 to developer console. It can be different from your development/upload key if you use AppGallery signing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to check about this issue:

1. Use the key tool to check whether the local APK signature is the same as the APK signature downloaded from the App Gallery.
2. Before building the APK, **configure the obfuscation configuration file** to prevent the HMS Core SDK from being obfuscated.
   so you need to check whether obfuscation scripts are configured.
   For Details,see [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-sdk-config-obfuscation-scripts-0000001061882229-V5?ha_source=hms1).